# check if class consist of img src, if not, hide it. jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a preset 7 image holder div, I send a request to php to retrieve works from a user, so let say if there are 3 works and I add to 3 img holders, I will have 4 empty image div, I don't know how i can check to hide the rest.

HTML

```
<div class="portfolio_thumb">
   <div class="portfolio_thumbImg_holder columns"><img src=""></div>
   <div class="portfolio_thumbImg_holder active columns"><img src=""></div>
   <div class="portfolio_thumbImg_holder columns"><img src=""></div>
   <div class="portfolio_thumbImg_holder columns"><img src=""></div>
   <div class="portfolio_thumbImg_holder columns"><img src=""></div>
   <div class="portfolio_thumbImg_holder columns"><img src=""></div>
   <div class="portfolio_thumbImg_holder columns"><img src=""></div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.portfolio_thumbImg_holder img').each(function(index, element) { 

    linksArray.push("http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[index].links);
    $(element).attr("src", linksArray[index]);
    titleArray.push(data[index].title);
    $(element).attr("title", titleArray[index]);
    descArray.push(data[index].desc);
    $(element).attr("desc", descArray[index]);
    alert("index:"+index + " " + linksArray[index] + " " + titleArray[index] + " " + descArray[index]);
});
```

How can I improve the jquery code to hide all the other `div`s that have no image loaded to it?

after code run,
my

```
<div class="portfolio_thumbImg_holder columns"><img src=""></div>
```

becomes

```
<div class="portfolio_thumbImg_holder columns"><img></div>
```

so i can't use

```
$(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder img[src='']").hide();
```

Update:

@jackDuong provided a code that is what i need

```
$(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder img:not([src])").parent().hide();
```

but after implementing on my current code, all the code after the $.each function won't run, any idea why?

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: ({id: idArray[index]}), // pass the name of clicked holder into php to query
            url: "CMS/PHP/retrieveAuthorWorks.php",
            success: function(data) {   
                // reset all the arrays value to store new values upon new click
                $('.portfolio_thumbImg_holder img').removeAttr("src");
                linksArray=[];  
                titleArray=[];  
                descArray=[];   
                $(".full_image_desc .title").html(data[0].title);
                $(".full_image_desc .info").html(data[0].desc);

                $('.portfolio_thumbImg_holder img').each(function(index, element) {                                                     
                    linksArray.push("http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[index].links);
                    $(element).attr("src", linksArray[index]);
                    titleArray.push(data[index].title);
                    $(element).attr("title", titleArray[index]);
                    descArray.push(data[index].desc);
                    $(element).attr("desc", descArray[index]);
                    //$(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder img:not([src])").parent().hide();
                }); 
                // from here onwards code won't run
                alert("hi");
                $(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder img:not([src])").parent().hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your mean: If tag image has no src attribute?

Comment: @jack duong, yup, because if the user only have 3 works, it will push into the first 3 div and ignore the rest, so i want to make a check if other div has no img src, i hide the div. Or simply if the work retrieved is only 3, delete the rest of the div. But i'm not sure how to execute

Answer (score 2):

I see... You added 7 elms to "**portfolio_thumb**".

Just do:

```
$(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder img[src='']").hide();
```

If you want to hide div (parent)
Just do:

```
$(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder img[src='']").parent().hide();
```

Try this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/duongtuanluc/2ktwa75e/

I saw you change the question.

If tag **img** has no attribute **src** 
Just do:

```
$(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder img:not([src])").parent().hide();
```

Try this example
http://jsfiddle.net/duongtuanluc/2ktwa75e/

Comment: is he want to hide the images or div?

Comment: i want to hide the div, anyway i get what u are saying, but when i retrieve 3 works, the other divs will become just <img> with the src missing already so i can't just use this code

Comment: how do i check if the <img> don't have a src? Instead of checking of src=''

Comment: Very simple: $(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder img[src='']").parent().hide(); if you want to hide div

Comment: @JackDuong bro it works if each person has only 1 image to show, because i put it in a loop so after the first img, it auto hide all the rest, i tried to finish the loop first before checking but i can't seem to put it at the end. I think i have some syntax problem w my code, let me check it out first.

Comment: @jack duong, code after the $.each function won't run, do u have any idea why? check out my updated code on my post

Comment: @Devon: Are you sure data.length equals $('.portfolio_thumbImg_holder img').length? I think there are some problems in your code at data[index].title (If data has 3 items, $('.portfolio_thumbImg_holder img') has 7 items then when index equals 4, data[4] is undefined, so you could not call title of undefined). If you need more support. Text me at 'lucltv' via Skype.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter for this

```
$(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder").filter(function() {
    var imgAttr = $(this).find("img").attr("src")
    return imgAttr == typeof undefined || imgAttr == false
}).hide();
```

or you can loop through each div to check whether it has image and then hide it

```
$(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder").each(function() {
    var imgAttr = $(this).find("img").attr("src")
    if (imgAttr == typeof undefined || imgAttr == false) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried it myself and finally got it..

i hide the div first

```
$(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder").hide();
```

after the retrieving is done, say 3 projects src will be added to the first 3 div, then i do

```
if($(this).has('src')){
    $(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder:nth("+index+")").show();
        alert("shown " + index);
    }
else
    {
    }
```

Final code

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: ({id: idArray[index]}), // pass the name of clicked holder into php to query
            url: "CMS/PHP/retrieveAuthorWorks.php",
            success: function(data) {   
                // reset all the arrays value to store new values upon new click
                $('.portfolio_thumbImg_holder img').removeAttr("src");
                linksArray=[];  
                titleArray=[];  
                descArray=[];   
                $(".full_image_desc .title").html(data[0].title);
                $(".full_image_desc .info").html(data[0].desc);

                $(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder").hide();
                $('.portfolio_thumbImg_holder img').each(function(index, element) { 

                        linksArray.push("http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[index].links);
                        $(element).attr("src", linksArray[index]);
                        titleArray.push(data[index].title);
                        $(element).attr("title", titleArray[index]);
                        descArray.push(data[index].desc);
                        $(element).attr("desc", descArray[index]);
                        alert("index:"+index + " " + linksArray[index] + " " + titleArray[index] + " " + descArray[index]);                     
                        if($(this).has('src')){
                            $(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder:nth("+index+")").show();
                            alert("shown " + index);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            });
```

Comment: It is not good solution. You don't need hide and show again. Just call $(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder img[src='']").parent().hide(); after bind data

Comment: problem is, although i preset a img src="", when i retrieve the files and push the data into the src, my remaining imageless div img will only have <img> with the src="" missing.. so the img[src=""] won't work

Comment: :) $(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder img:not([src])").parent().hide();

Comment: @JackDuong omg this is what i need.. list as a answer so i can accept